# What is the purpose of the client key in etcd cluster client auth?

Tags: tls1.2, etcd

I currently setting up a `etcd` cluster with three nodes for my Microk8s cluster following [this](http://play.etcd.io/install) and [this](https://computingforgeeks.com/setup-etcd-cluster-on-centos-debian-ubuntu/) guides. I want to enable client and peer auth via TLS using a self-signed CA.

The [documentation for Transport Security](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/op-guide/security/) states the following in this regard:

> Client-to-server communication:
>
> --cert-file=: Certificate used for SSL/TLS connections to etcd. When this option is set, advertise-client-urls can use the HTTPS schema.
>
> --key-file=: Key for the certificate. Must be unencrypted.

> Peer (server-to-server / cluster) communication:
>
> --peer-cert-file=: Certificate used for SSL/TLS connections between peers. This will be used both for listening on the peer address as well as sending requests to other peers.
>
> --peer-key-file=: Key for the certificate. Must be unencrypted.

From what I understand is that

- a.) peer communication occurs between `etcd` nodes and
- b.) client communication between `etcd` nodes and my Microk8s cluster

I also understand that for peer communication I need both the `cert` and the `key`.
In the examples and SO questions checked (see below), the same set of `key` and `cert` for client and peer auth is used.

What I do not understand is why do I have to provide my client `key` to the `etcd` server as I want it to be a secret of the client? It would be great if someone could shed some light or tell me where I am wrong with my assumption. Thank you.

Examples and Questions:

- [62559058](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559058/cant-connect-to-the-etcd-of-kubernetes)
- [32912699](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912699/unable-to-setup-kubernetes-against-tls-secured-etcd)
- http://play.etcd.io/install